# How to add Buy now button in Magento 2.1.8?

Tags: magento-2.1.8, buy-now

How to add **buy now button** in **Magento 2.1.8** ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below free extension to add buy now button.

https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow

That extension will add "Buy Now" button on product view page and product list page to process directly checkout.

Comment: Hi@Kishan Patadia, This is working only Mozilla browser in google chrome it is not working.Please check screenshot https://prnt.sc/ink1qm.Can you please help me?

Comment: In google chrome Click the buy now button and generate URL is https://localhost/magento2/buynow/cart/. In Mozilla click the buy now button the generated URL is http://localhost/magento2/checkout/